# Immersive Stick Mode in Android 4.4

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-fullscreen

I am trying to create a demo of how immersive mode works in android 4.4. I did that but I have to paste same below code in all the activies.

```
 @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (hasFocus) {
            this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            );
        }
    }
```

### Question

Suppose I have two `activities` & I start from `A` Activity then this code hide the navigation bar + bottom back button bar, so here I click on `button` and start the second `B` Activity then here for few seconds navigation bar + bottom back button bar appears until `onWindowFocusChanged` get called that is really annoying.

Is there any way to make it immersive mode of entire application at single place so that whenever I start a new activity then navigation + bottom back button bar won't display for few seconds ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make an abstract `BaseActivity` that configures immersive mode and make all other `Activities` inherit from it

Comment: Yup that will solve a problem of pasting same code in each activity but my main question whenever I start a new activity then navigation + bottom back button bar appears for few seconds which I don't want that is really annoying